# The Chofetz Chaim on the attitude of the people during the Purim-story

Tags: translation, purim, mordechai

I saw in the sefer [(החפץ חיים חייו ופעלו ג )](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/8052/p/145/t/0.24890843172451051234/fs/YsaRigYYFJuZKAegLfjCj1B0iWQN56BhZ435UPrck04l/start/0/end/9/c) that the Chofetz Chaim explains the attitude of the people during the Purim-story. It seems that he says that our ancestors feared that they could not uphold the Torah and its mitzvos, due to the world they were living in, being scattered around the world. "Just bown down to Haman" would be much easier, according to this, but Mordechai refused to bow down to Haman, meaning that no matter what, Mordechai kept Torah and mitzvos, to the full extent.

> חז"ל קובעים שרק בזמנו של אחשורוש קבלו היהודים את התורה בדצונם הטוב בעוד שבהר סיני קבלוה גאונס דרוש להבין כיצד יתכן שדוד המדבר המתואר כ"דור דעה ב"מעמד הנבחר כפי שמכונה מעמד הר סיני יהיו זקוקים לאונס בקבלת התודה לאחר שהצהירו פה אחד נעשה קודם ל"נשמע
> התשובה היא' שלא שסירבו לקבל את התורה חס ושלום אלא שחז"ל מתכוונים בזה לבטא אח הרגשות הפקפוק שהרגישו אבותינו באותה שעה בחששם שמא לא יהיה בבחמי תמיד להחזיק מעמד בעולם לפי התודה שעם ישראל כשהוא מפוזד בין אומות העולם לא יוכל לשמור על קיומו העצמאי בהיותו מוקף עולם של שונאים לבלי לאכול מפחם לבלי לשחות מיינם לבלי להתחתן בהם הן כל זה ומשמש גודם לאיבה סיבת גזרתו של המן הדי היתה משום שמרדכי בהתאם לדין התורה סירב להשתחוות לו בנשאו עבודה זרה על לבו חז"ל
>
> והנה נתדחש נס פודים אחשורוש נשתנה פתאום לחלוטין ראש שדיו שזה לא כבד
> פקד על הכל להשתחוות לו נתלה בפקודתו והיהודי מרדכי נתרומם בחוד משגה
> למלך הפכפך שכמותו יום לפני כן הדשה שדם יהודי יחשב כהפקר וכאן משתדל הוא
> במלוא יכלתו להשביע את רצונם של יהודיו מצד אחד איפוא מפלה נצחת של שונאי
> ישראל במדה שעד היום הזה משמתכוונים לציין עצמתה של מפלה ממשילים אותה
> ב"מפלתו של המן ומצד שני כבוד במדד שכזו לאומה הישראלית הודות לנסיון זה
> נוכחו באפשרות שניתנת ליהודים בגלותם לחיות חיים יהודיים טהורים נוכחו
> לדעת ששומה עליהם בעיקר להשתוקק לשמור על התורה להיות מוכנים למסור את
> נפשותיהם על קיומה והשי"ת יהיה בעזרם התודה מגנא ומצלא לפיכך אין כל פלא
> ש"הדור קבלוה בימי אחשודוש היות ונוכחו להבין שאין התורה סותדת את

The Gemara in [Shabbos 88a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that in the days of Achashverosh, the Jewish people accepted the Torah again. What then, is the explanation attributed to the Chofetz Chaim? Could someone explain it to me (and provide an translation)?

Could someone maybe translate this piece for me? I have troubles understanding the Hebrew.

Comment: It would seem the Chofetz chain is referring to the situation prior to the whole story, when only Mordechai didn’t bow. The Gemara is referring after the whole story when they all realized their mistake

Comment: @chatzkel interesting, wasn’t aware of this. Could you maybe provide this in answer form, including translation of the piece I mentioned? It this idea mentioned further, about the attitude of the people prior to this?

Comment: "קימו וקבלו עליהם" is usually explained to refer to a "new kabbolas hatorah" after the Purim story.

Comment: @Chatzkel care to provide an English translation?

Comment: @Esther thanks, but why especially?

Comment: @shmuel I’m not especially good with translations

Comment: @Chatzkel does it say that Haman was the only one not bowing down? Does it explain why the Yiden felt this way? Maybe someone can help?

Comment: He’s explaining why the yidden in the midbar didn’t want to accept it willingly. They were scared what would happen if they went to galus. But once they went, and mordechai held strong, and they saw that he was right and they were saved, they accepted it willingly